# Text Processing : extract fixed number of numbers from text

Tags: r

I am trying the following :

```
gg <-c("delete from below 110 11031133 11 11031135 110",
"delete froml #10989431 from adfdaf 10888022 <(>&<)> 10888018",
"this is for the deletion of an incorrect numberss that is no longer used for asd09 and sd040",
"please delete the following mangoes from trey 10246211 1 10821224 1 10821248 1 10821249",
"from 11015647 helppp 1 na from 0050 - zfhhhh 10840637 1")



pattern_to_find <- c('\\d{4,}')

aa <- str_extract_all(gg, pattern_to_find)
aa
```

with this code I am able to extact any numeric pattern with number greater than a fixed number. But if I want to extract 2 didit number then it picks up all the first two numbers from the numeric field .

```
pattern_to_find <- c('\\d{2}').

How can I modify my pattern to work on both ways. 

Regards, 
R
```

Comment: What is your expectred output

Comment: Do you need `str_extract_all(gg, "\\b\\d{4,}\\b")`

Comment: Or may be `str_extract_all(gg, "(?<=\\b\\d{2} )\\d{4,}")`

Answer (score 1):

Tidyverse solution:

```
library(tidyverse)

pattern_to_find <- c('\\d{2,}')

aa <- str_extract_all(gg, pattern_to_find)
```

Base R solution:

```
base_aa <- regmatches(gg, gregexpr(pattern_to_find, gg))
```